# SQL: extract numbers from string fields

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Report for clients with several conditions.
The result must contain 'upper_income_level' - the upper limit of the `'cust_income_level'` column.

`'cust_income_level'` field  has for example similar content: `‘G: 130,000 - 149,999’`. How to extract only `149999` and convert to an integer?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question, provide a few rows of sample data, including enough columns of data to help us understand your table, and a sample required output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without regular expressions, you can use

```
substr( cust_income_level, instr( cust_income_level, '-') + 2 ) as cust_income_level
```

If you want to use it as numeric in an ORDER BY, you can use function TO_NUMBER(), but this is error prone since you'll get errors when the value isn't an actual number value.

```
to_number( substr( cust_income_level, instr( cust_income_level, '-') + 2 )) as cust_income_level
```

Instead, for the ORDER BY, you can add leading zero's and use that value to get the correct order. If there is a value which isn't a number, it will be presented in the results, but at least you won't get an error.

```
lpad( substr( cust_income_level, instr( cust_income_level, '-') + 2 ), 9, '0')
```

Example above will add leading zero's until the value is 9 characters long

- '3' becomes '000000003'
- '40' becomes '000000040'
- etc.

Sorting on the results above will lead to a correct ordering of numbers in a varchar2 datatype.

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me how to convert it to integer (because I need it in ORDER BY)

Comment: You can, but be aware that you will get errors when it is not convertable to a number, in case the value contains an alphanumeric character. Instead it is possible better to order by on the value which contains leading zeros. I did update the answer.

Comment: You’re welcome, please mark the answer as accepted if you’re satisfied. That way anyone else will see the question as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the numbers at the end of the string, you can use:

```
select replace(regexp_substr(cust_income_level, '[0-9,]+$'), ',', '')
```